# Eclipse files does not exist in workspace but does in remote system

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a remote project in eclipse. Usually it works fine but sometimes, my explorer, says a file does not exist when I open it. The files does exist in my remote system explorer and in my local explorer file list, it just cant open.

Even if I refresh the project. Any suggestions.

Comment: What kind of file? In which editor are you trying to open it? Not all editors support the mechanism RSE implements.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible suggestions**

- You might be having your workspace in virtual machine,  which keeps refreshing at regular intervals. Recommending to save your workspace in myDrive or myDesktop (yours) where it would be safe.
- You eclipse might have synced up with version control( like svn/cvs) at remote. Always disconnect from your version control while you have with development work for the day. And i recommend you to make  a local copy of remote repository in your desktop.